# Squid ACL Whitelist not working

Tags: squid, pfsense

I have Squid proxy in transparent mode for HTTP/HTTPS with splice all mode. I want a bunch of URL to skip Squid so I thought to add the DNS record to the whitelist however it seems like the whitelist is ignored by squid
Below my list

```
.tdesktop.com
.whatsapp.com
.whatsapp.net
.facebook.com

[2.4.0-RC][olivierif@pfSense.sw11.lab]/home/olivierif: sudo squid -k parse
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Startup: Initializing Authentication Schemes ...
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Startup: Initialized Authentication Scheme 'basic'
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Startup: Initialized Authentication Scheme 'digest'
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Startup: Initialized Authentication Scheme 'negotiate'
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Startup: Initialized Authentication Scheme 'ntlm'
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Startup: Initialized Authentication.
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing Configuration File: /usr/local/etc/squid/squid.conf (depth 0)
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: http_port 192.168.50.254:3128 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=10MB cert=/usr/local/etc/squid/serverkey.pem capath=/usr/local/share/certs/ cipher=EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+RC4:EECDH:EDH+aRSA:!RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS tls-dh=prime256v1:/etc/dh-parameters.2048 options=NO_SSLv2,NO_SSLv3,NO_TLSv1,SINGLE_DH_USE,SINGLE_ECDH_USE
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: http_port 127.0.0.1:3128 intercept ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=10MB cert=/usr/local/etc/squid/serverkey.pem capath=/usr/local/share/certs/ cipher=EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+RC4:EECDH:EDH+aRSA:!RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS tls-dh=prime256v1:/etc/dh-parameters.2048 options=NO_SSLv2,NO_SSLv3,NO_TLSv1,SINGLE_DH_USE,SINGLE_ECDH_USE
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Starting Authentication on port 127.0.0.1:3128
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Disabling Authentication on port 127.0.0.1:3128 (interception enabled)
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: https_port 127.0.0.1:3129 intercept ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=10MB cert=/usr/local/etc/squid/serverkey.pem capath=/usr/local/share/certs/ cipher=EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+RC4:EECDH:EDH+aRSA:!RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS tls-dh=prime256v1:/etc/dh-parameters.2048 options=NO_SSLv2,NO_SSLv3,NO_TLSv1,SINGLE_DH_USE,SINGLE_ECDH_USE
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Starting Authentication on port 127.0.0.1:3129
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Disabling Authentication on port 127.0.0.1:3129 (interception enabled)
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: icp_port 0
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: digest_generation off
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: dns_v4_first on
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: pid_filename /var/run/squid/squid.pid
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: cache_effective_user squid
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: cache_effective_group proxy
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: error_default_language en
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: icon_directory /usr/local/etc/squid/icons
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: visible_hostname localhost
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: cache_mgr admin@localhost
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: access_log /var/squid/logs/access.log
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: cache_log /var/squid/logs/cache.log
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: cache_store_log none
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: netdb_filename /var/squid/logs/netdb.state
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: pinger_enable off
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: pinger_program /usr/local/libexec/squid/pinger
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: sslcrtd_program /usr/local/libexec/squid/ssl_crtd -s /var/squid/lib/ssl_db -M 4MB -b 2048
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: sslcrtd_children 5
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: sslproxy_capath /usr/local/share/certs/
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: sslproxy_options NO_SSLv2,NO_SSLv3,NO_TLSv1,SINGLE_DH_USE,SINGLE_ECDH_USE
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: sslproxy_cipher EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+RC4:EECDH:EDH+aRSA:!RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: sslproxy_cert_error allow all
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: logfile_rotate 3
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: debug_options rotate=3
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: shutdown_lifetime 3 seconds
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: acl localnet src  192.168.50.0/24
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: forwarded_for on
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: httpd_suppress_version_string on
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: uri_whitespace strip
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: acl dynamic urlpath_regex cgi-bin \?
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: cache deny dynamic
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: cache_mem 128 MB
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: maximum_object_size_in_memory 512 KB
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: memory_replacement_policy heap GDSF
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: cache_replacement_policy heap LFUDA
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: minimum_object_size 0 KB
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: maximum_object_size 4 MB
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: cache_dir ufs /var/squid/cache 1000 16 256
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: offline_mode off
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: cache_swap_low 90
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: cache_swap_high 95
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: cache allow all
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: refresh_pattern ^ftp:    1440  20%  10080
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: refresh_pattern ^gopher:  1440  0%  1440
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0  0%  0
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: refresh_pattern .    0  20%  4320
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: acl allsrc src all
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: acl safeports port 21 70 80 210 280 443 488 563 591 631 777 901  3128 3129 1025-65535
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: acl sslports port 443 563
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: acl purge method PURGE
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: acl connect method CONNECT
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: acl HTTP proto HTTP
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: acl HTTPS proto HTTPS
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: acl step1 at_step SslBump1
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: acl step2 at_step SslBump2
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: acl step3 at_step SslBump3
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: acl allowed_subnets src 192.168.0.0/16
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: acl whitelist dstdom_regex -i "/var/squid/acl/whitelist.acl"
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: http_access allow manager localhost
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: http_access deny manager
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: http_access allow purge localhost
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: http_access deny purge
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: http_access deny !safeports
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: http_access deny CONNECT !sslports
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: http_access allow localhost
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: request_body_max_size 0 KB
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: delay_pools 1
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: delay_class 1 2
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: delay_parameters 1 -1/-1 -1/-1
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: delay_initial_bucket_level 100
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: delay_access 1 allow allsrc
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: url_rewrite_program /usr/local/bin/squidGuard -c /usr/local/etc/squidGuard/squidGuard.conf
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: url_rewrite_bypass off
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: url_rewrite_children 16 startup=8 idle=4 concurrency=0
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: http_access allow whitelist
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: acl sglog url_regex -i sgr=ACCESSDENIED
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: http_access deny sglog
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: ssl_bump peek step1
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: ssl_bump splice all
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: http_access allow allowed_subnets
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: http_access allow localnet
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: http_access deny allsrc
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: icap_enable on
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: icap_send_client_ip on
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: icap_send_client_username off
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: icap_client_username_encode off
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: icap_client_username_header X-Authenticated-User
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: icap_preview_enable on
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: icap_preview_size 1024
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: icap_service service_avi_req reqmod_precache icap://127.0.0.1:1344/squid_clamav bypass=off
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: adaptation_access service_avi_req allow all
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: icap_service service_avi_resp respmod_precache icap://127.0.0.1:1344/squid_clamav bypass=on
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Processing: adaptation_access service_avi_resp allow all
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Initializing https proxy context
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Initializing http_port 192.168.50.254:3128 SSL context
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Using certificate in /usr/local/etc/squid/serverkey.pem
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Initializing http_port 127.0.0.1:3128 SSL context
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Using certificate in /usr/local/etc/squid/serverkey.pem
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Initializing https_port 127.0.0.1:3129 SSL context
2017/10/02 13:19:20| Using certificate in /usr/local/etc/squid/serverkey.pem
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Run `squid3 -k parse` and post the output to see more details. If something is wrong with your whitelist, squid should show it.